# Jenkins job hangs during Bitbucket pull

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have 2 differend hosts with Jenkins: Host1 and Host2.
On Host1 Jenkins was successfully configured and job takes the latest changes from Bitbucket and build the project.
Now I need to configure the same job on the Host2 and I get a problem: job hangs during Bitbucket pull. This is the last message that I get from console:

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags
>   --progress http://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Jenkins configurations are the same on the both hosts. I read few tutorials that the issue may be in ssh connection, so I configured trusted_hosts for Host2, added them to .ssh folder but nothing helps.

A full log looks like this:

Building in workspace E:\JenkinsWorkspace

> C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url http://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git # timeout=10
>   Fetching upstream changes from http://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git 
>   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
>   C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress 
>   http://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git  +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are not using SSH, so the issue is not in the SSH connection for sure.

Comment: Also Bitbucket hosts the repositories using HTTPS, not plain HTTP. It sends a 307 redirect in case you want to reach a repo by HTTP and my git client copes with it, but maybe your installation doesn't. Try changing `http://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git` to  `https://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git` (http -> https being the relevant bit)

Comment: Another thought: I've never used GIT repos through HTTPS in a Jenkins build, but my idea is that build may be blocked by a password prompt (which cannot be answered as it's non-interactive).

Comment: @jannis Tried with https - doesn't help, same freeze.

Comment: @jannis The most annoying thing, that I have the same configuration on the Host1 and everything works there.

Comment: Can you remote into the Jenkins agent and try executing the commands manually?

Comment: Do you mean to write Windows batch command script instead of git plugin? I have full access to Jenkins

Comment: Go to the Jenkins agent, open the console, create a new temp folder, cd into it and type: `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe clone https://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git` and then `ping bitbucket.org`

Comment: E:\tempfolder>"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" clone https://my_login@bitbucket.org/my_project/project.git 
Cloning into 'project'...
and hangs again.

Comment: If I do the same with usual cmd, then I get credentials pop-up opened

Comment: What do you mean by 'usual cmd'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109227/discussion-between-stivin-and-jannis).